# How to optimize my code to make it faster?

Tags: java, optimization

I am currently working on a problem of an online judge. However, my code keeps exceeding the TimeLimit, which is only 1 second. I have used the `Scanner` and `System.out.print()` however I have been told that such methods will make my code slower and will consume more memory, that is way I buffered the input and output. I cannot use types such as `long` or `int` as the data stored the variables is longer than those values.

Here is the code:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException{
        java.io.InputStreamReader iSR = new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in);
        java.io.BufferedReader bR = new java.io.BufferedReader(iSR, 16 * 1024);
        BufferedWriter bW = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        String tL;
        BigDecimal PRA = BigDecimal.ZERO, PRB = BigDecimal.ZERO, PA = BigDecimal.ZERO, PB = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        int input = Integer.parseInt(bR.readLine());
        for(int j = 0; j < input; j++){
            tL = bR.readLine();
            String [] = arr = tL.split(" ");
            PA = BigDecimal.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]));
            PB = BigDecimal.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
            PRA = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(arr[2]));
            PRB = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(arr[3]));
            PRA = PRA.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)); PRA = PRA.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
            PRB = PRB.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)); PRB = PRB.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
            int i = 1;
            while(PA.compareTo(PB) < 0 && i < 103){
                BigDecimal ibd = BigDecimal.valueOf(i);
                PA = PA.multiply(PRA).multiply(ibd);
                PB = PB.multiply(PRB).multiply(ibd);
                i++;
            }
            i--;
            if(i > 100) bW.write("Mais de 1 seculo.\n");
            else bW.write(String.valueOf(i) + " anos.\n");
            bW.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"I am currently working on a problem of an online judge."` -- If this is for an online contest, shouldn't you be solving this by yourself? Just wondering.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Is not a contest. I am just practicing, thanks for wondering anyway.

Comment: What the heck is this...

Comment: making j instances of bufferedwriter is not helping.

Comment: Repeatedly/redundantly creating `BigDecimal.valueOf(100)` and `BigDecimal.valueOf(i)` isn't helping either.

Comment: This is a code review question. It really belongs on the Code Review discussion rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown You are right, I have just edited.

Comment: @keshlam followed your advice. Please check the code again. (However TimeLimitExceeded).

Answer (score 3):

One point..

You shouldn't do `tL.split("\\s")` multiple times. Just do it once, assign it to a variable and use that instead.

Comment: Actually, I would create a new instance if I follow your advice, which  wouldn't help. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Hans: so instead by doing it your way, you're creating four new instances instead of one. Can't Tell's way is obviously better and obviously *does* help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Instead of creating 5 instances I am creating 4.

Comment: @Hans: No, you are creating four instead of one! 1+ to Can't tell. Please follow his advice.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok, maybe I am confused, Should I create an Array?

Comment: @Hans: You're already creating 4 arrays. Wouldn't you be much better off creating one as Can't Tell advises you to do? Please at least up-vote has answer.

Comment: @Hans: I think that you're confused on the difference between creating a *variable* and creating an object. A variable doesn't cost much at all, but your code creates ***four*** String array *objects* when it could get by with creating just ***one***, and this can be expensive inside of a for loop.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hold on, I am not creating 4 arrays anywhere. I taking the output of the split array. Which contains 4 elements.

Comment: @Hans: you are quite confused. Every time you call `tL.split("\\s")` you ***create*** a ***new*** String array. I'm wasting my breathe here and won't discuss this further as we're hitting a wall.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh, ok, ok, now I get it, I'll see what is the best way to do it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I corrected please check the code. Thanks for insisting. And still Time Limit exceeded.